# Multiple a time with a number using javascript

Tags: javascript, time

can someone help with my code. I would like to multiply a number such as 20 with a time e.g. 35:00. I need this to work out the total cost per employee based on how much they have worked a week. I have just multiplied the two fields containing these values to see if it works, but it doesn't. Here is the code

```
var total = util.printd("timeDiff") * ("Total_Cost");
this.getField("Total_Cost").value = total;
```

Thank you

Comment: What library are you using because this is not standard JavaScript

Comment: what should the answer be? 20 * 35:00 = 700:00 , 20 * 35:00 = 11.66667

Comment: Divilner,  yes that is what i need "20 *35:00 = 700:00"

Comment: calculating time or money?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the time and parse it.

Then you need to calculate each part seperate.

```
var timeArr = util.printd("timeDiff").split(':');
var total = Total_Cost;
var hours = timeArr[0] * total;
var minutes = timeArr[1] * total;
this.getField("Total_Cost").value = hours + ':' + minutes;
```

Comment: Thank you Divelner, this helped alot.

Answer (score 1):

The time must be splitted and reassambled with the correct time value. The result is cost total.

```js
var timeDiff = '35:20',
    costPerHour = 20,
    total;

function getDecimalTime(s) {
    var p = s.split(':');
    return +p[0] + +p[1] / 60;
}

total = getDecimalTime(timeDiff) * costPerHour;
document.write(total);
```